# Changing format of CSV from MySQL DB using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I found a similar question but there was no solution due to lack of information.
I have the code below which outputs data from the connected MySQL DB to a formatted CSV file in the following format…

```
First Name:Surname:GCNumber:Dept:Start Date:Introduction:Theory:Fire Safety:Governance:
John:Smith:123456:HR:03/08/2013:Pass:Pass:Fail:Pass:
Jane:Watson:123445:IT:03/08/2013:Pass:Fail:Pass:Pass:
Mark:Byron:123442:IT:03/08/2013:Fail:Fail:Not Done:Not Done:
```

`:` = used just to show each column

It just outputs all the rows and columns that are in the database in the same structure, and renaming the column headers to be more friendly when imported into excel.
What I need is to change to format of this output to the following…

```
First Name:Surname:GCNumber:Dept:Email:Start Date:Module:Status:
John:Smith:123456:HR:03/08/2013:Introduction:Pass:
John:Smith:123456:HR:03/08/2013:Theory:Pass:
John:Smith:123456:HR:03/08/2013:Fire Safety:Fail:
John:Smith:123456:HR:03/08/2013:Governance:Pass:
Jane:Watson:123445:IT:03/08/2013:Introduction:Pass:
Jane:Watson:123445:IT:03/08/2013:Theory:Fail:
Jane:Watson:123445:IT:03/08/2013:Fire Safety:Pass:
Jane:Watson:123445:IT:03/08/2013:Governance:Pass:
Mark:Byron:123442:IT:03/08/2013:Introduction:Fail:
Mark:Byron:123442:IT:03/08/2013:Theory:Fail:
Mark:Byron:123442:IT:03/08/2013:Fire Safety:Not Done:
Mark:Byron:123442:IT:03/08/2013:Governance:Not Done:
```

`:` = used just to show each column

So Rather than one entry for each person, and results of each module they have done I need it to be a separate entry for each module that person has done.
In total there are more fields to this DB and 35 modules but I've cut this down for illustration purposes here.

Being a bit of a newbie with PHP etc I'm struggling to get my head around how to do this.
Is this possible or would it be easier to try and change the structure of the DB to be in the desired format?

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be great.
Tony

```
<?php

function exportMysqlToCsv($table,$filename = 'db-snapshot.csv')
{

    $sql_query = "select fldFirstname as 'First Name',
     fldSurname as 'Surname',
     fldGMCNumber as 'GCNumber', 
     fldDestDept as 'Dept',
     fldStartDate as 'Start Date',
     fldModule1 as 'Introduction',
     fldModule2 as 'Theory',
     fldModule3 as 'Fire Safety',
     fldModule4 as 'Governance'
     from $table";

    // Gets the data from the database
    $result = mysql_query($sql_query);

    $f = fopen('php://temp', 'wt');
    $first = true;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if ($first) {
            fputcsv($f, array_keys($row));
            $first = false;
        }
        fputcsv($f, $row);
    } // end while

    $size = ftell($f);
    rewind($f);

    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Content-Length: $size");

 // Output to browser with appropriate mime type, you choose ;)
    header("Content-type: text/x-csv");
    // header("Content-type: text/csv");
    // header("Content-type: application/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
    fpassthru($f);
    exit;
}

?>
```

Comment: Show me your table structure and sample data....actually with that info it's gonna be easy to solve this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UNIONS for this:

```
SELECT fldFirstname as 'First Name', fldSurname as 'Surname', 
  fldGMCNumber as 'GCNumber', fldDestDept as 'Dept', 
  fldStartDate as 'Start Date', fldEndDate as 'End Date', 
  'Introduction' as 'Module', fldModule1 as 'Status' FROM records
UNION
SELECT fldFirstname,fldSurname,fldGMCNumber,fldDestDept,fldStartDate,fldEndDate,
  'Theory',fldModule2 FROM records
UNION
SELECT fldFirstname,fldSurname,fldGMCNumber,fldDestDept,fldStartDate,fldEndDate,
  'Fire Safety',fldModule3 FROM records
UNION
SELECT fldFirstname,fldSurname,fldGMCNumber,fldDestDept,fldStartDate,fldEndDate,
  'Governance',fldModule4 FROM records
ORDER BY Surname, `First Name`, Module;
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21201/10)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a pivot on my query to the DB. Check under
[If I have a MySQL table looking something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

So you would basically create a table with rows describing your module:

```
Module 
1 | Introduction 
2 | Theory 
3 | Fire Safety 
4 | Governance
```

Then join it to table above and use a "Case" syntax to achieve your request.